# Parsing date is giving error: month out of range in Go

Tags: go

I have a date:

```
myStringDate = "27-09-2019"
```

that is a string, and I need to convert to time.Time in Go.

So, I do:

```
date, err = time.Parse("01-02-2006", myStringDate)
```

And I get an error:

```
data:<*time.ParseError>(0xc000098140)
:<time.ParseError>
Layout:"01-02-2006"
Value:"27-09-2019"
LayoutElem:"01"
ValueElem:"-09-2019"
Message:": month out of range"
```

Nevertheless, the layout I use to parse it seems OK.

I am parsing several files, all coming from the same sources, and the other file can be parsed without any problems

What point am I missing ?

Comment: just a wild guess, although the message says it clearly: you are mixing US and international format. That's why `27` is out of month range.

Comment: Your input: `"27-09-2019"`, in that, `27` is the day, `09` is the month, so you have to use the layout: `"02-01-2006"` and not `"01-02-2006"`.

Comment: Yes, but I had it working like this for a while, so, I am a bit surprised not to have met this error before....

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro Then it looks you didn't have any samples with days > 12.

Comment: @icza Yep, I guess so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Per the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse), the layout parameter to `Parse` is the canonical date "Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006" represented in the desired format. That means the layout you gave is MM-DD-YYYY, when your data appears to be DD-MM-YYYY. If that is the case, your layout string should be `02-01-2006`.

```
myStringDate := "27-09-2019"
date, err := time.Parse("02-01-2006", myStringDate)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/qUEDtcG1v3W